# How to Wrap a text of a cell <td>?

Tags: css

Here is a code

```
<style type="text/css">.BreakWord {word-break: break-all; }
```

```
 <table width=40>
  <tr>
  <td class=BreakWord>
  hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

But it is not wrapping text.

Any Idea?

Thanx

Comment: Which Browser? I thought `word-break: break-all` _doesn't work_ in FF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">.BreakWord {word-break: break-all; }</style>
</head>
<body>

    <div>
    <table width="40px"  style="table-layout:fixed;">
  <tr>
  <td class="BreakWord">
  hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Micheal: I tried it out earlier, but i saw yours when i wanted to re-submit mine. I should have referenced you, im sorry.

Answer (score 7):

Please note the above answer does not work with FF and a couple other browsers.  I have taken my example from a couple different websites on google.  I have tested this on ff 5.0, IE 8.0, and Chrome 10.

```
.wrapword{
white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
word-break: break-all;
white-space: normal;
}

<table style="table-layout:fixed; width:400px">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapword">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this code for your cell:

```
<style type="text/css">.BreakWord {white-space: normal; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `table-layout:fixed;`
to your table.
Also it's `word-wrap: break-word;`.